# Filter dynamic object with many conditions and values. (JS)

Tags: javascript

This is a restaurant filter project that seens to work well, but I can't figure out how to filter for 5-stars only or in conbination with other filters.

All others filters work well. The unwantedFieldsFilter works in reverse.

Any idea?, or how would you accomplish this?  thanks

Run snippet, please.Run snippet, please.Run snippet, please.

```js
let table = document.getElementById('table');
    let form = document.getElementById('form');

    const restaurants = [{
        name: "dennys",
        type: "dinner",
        open: "yes",
        price: "$$",
        stars: "5"
      },
      {
        name: "mcdonalds",
        type: "fastfood",
        open: "no",
        price: "$",
        stars: "3"
      },
      {
        name: "rubios",
        type: "fastfood",
        open: "yes",
        price: "$$",
        stars: "4"
      },
      {
        name: "polloloco",
        type: "fastfood",
        open: "no",
        price: "$",
        stars: "5"
      },
      {
        name: "kfc",
        type: "fastfood",
        open: "no",
        price: "$",
        stars: "3"
      },
      {
        name: "deltaco",
        type: "fastfood",
        open: "no",
        price: "$",
        stars: "1"
      },
      {
        name: "olivegarden",
        type: "dinner",
        open: "no",
        price: "$$",
        stars: "4"
      },
      {
        name: "fiveguys",
        type: "fastfood",
        open: "no",
        price: "$$",
        stars: "5"
      }
    ]

    displayer(restaurants)

    function ruleOut(arr, filterObj) {
      return arr.filter(person => {

        for (field in filterObj) {
          var val = person[field]
          if (filterObj[field].indexOf(val) > -1) return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
    }


    form.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
      evt.preventDefault()

      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check');
      var values = [],
        unwantedFieldsFilter = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (!checkboxes[i].checked) {
          values.push("");
        } else {
          values.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        }
      }

      unwantedFieldsFilter = {
        type: values[0],
        open: values[1],
        price: values[2],
        stars: values[3]
      }

      let filtered = ruleOut(restaurants, unwantedFieldsFilter);

      displayer(filtered)
    })


    function displayer(filtered) {
    table.innerHTML = "";
    filtered.forEach(rest => {

    table.innerHTML += `
    <tr>
      <td>${rest.name}</td>
      <td>${rest.type}</td>
      <td>${rest.open}</td>
      <td>${rest.price}</td>
      <td>${rest.stars}</td>
    </tr> `


    })
    }
```

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #target {
      font-size: large;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 600px;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: white;
    }

    body {
      background-color: aliceblue;
    }

    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    td,
    th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    th {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }

    #buttons {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #buttons button {
      padding: 10px;
      color: rgba(13, 32, 7, 0.596);
      font-weight: 900;
    }

    input[type='checkbox'] {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 2px solid #555;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    label {
      margin-right: 10px;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    form {
      background-color: rgb(231, 248, 221);
      padding: 10px;
    }

    input[type='submit'] {
      width: 80px;
      height: 30px;
      font-size: large;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div id="buttons">

      <form action="" id="form">
        <input type="checkbox" id="fastfood" name="check" value="dinner">
        <label for="fastfood"> FastFood</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="open24" name="check" value="no">
        <label for="open24"> Open24</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="check" value="$">
        <label for="vehicle3"> Price $$</label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="check" value="5">
        <label for="vehicle3"> 5 Stars</label>

        <input type="submit" value="Filter">

      </form>

    </div>

    <div id="target">

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Restaurant</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Open 24</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>5 Stars</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="table">

        </tbody>

      </table>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly you want the checkboxes to work? Because the $$ box for instance can either be checked or not, but in theory you have three options: 1. show all restaurants 2. show only $ ones 3. show only $$ ones

Comment: Anyway, here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/tqo0951p/

Comment: You got it right!!!  OMG!!   Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: You code is very clean and amazing!!  I don't know how I could become good as you!  I was trying this exercise for 4 days now and my brain was about to quit!!

Comment: Well, just write JS code for five years or so and you can write stuff like this in your sleep ;)

Comment: If you decide to create a JS curse in Udemy or somewhere else I'll be the first to buy it!